# Unable to Update-FileDistributionService due to old exchange server entry

Tags: exchange, remove

I am getting following error when I a trying to update File Distributionservices as shown below.

The error pops up with name of my old CAS server which means mailbox server still have entry. Please assist how to get rid of this.  I want to remove server entry : vexchangecas from my mailbox server as shown below. Error pops up when running following command:

```
Get-ClientAccessServer|Update-FileDistributionService
```

[image: Unable to update CAS fildistribution services due to old cas server entry]

Comment: If the server truly doesn't exist, you'd have to ADSI into Exchange services and remove the server as an available namespace.  Does Get-ClientAccessServer alone populate that entry and does it still live in various configurations?

Comment: Yes, Chaseabbott it there was an a old server entry in my exchange farm and I deleted with ADSI 2 weeks ago and the issue has been resolved.